# Problems with .xlsx files in .net Core after hosting on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, xlsx

the problem is that when I deploy my .NET Core application to my IIS server, the application is working fine but the places that is using a .XLSX file is not working.

I basically have some functions that need a static predefined .xlsx file but they  don't seem to have been deployed with the application, tried to put it in root and in the wwwroot folder, does not work.

I am quite new to deploying to IIS and using the Web Deploy function in Visual Studio so I hope some clever heads can help me.
I have about 7 excels files that needs to be with the program.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is that the files are missing and not that some processing on them fails for some reason (there should be no Office on that server)? If you can access the file through "localhost" on your dev machine, then try a similar path to your IIS server.

Comment: Pretty sure, as I am trying to find the files and they are no where to be found on the server, also I am using Epplus and the server has office installed.

Comment: Is the "build action" (see properties in solution explorer) set to "Content"?

Comment: A server should *not* have Office installed, Office is not meant to be run in a server environment. And with EPPlus you probably do not need it.

Comment: Ok I have gotten the files now on the server, thanks for the advice, but the path is still a problem does not seem that it is getting it even if I hard code the path down. Any advice?

Comment: See the answer by Nischal for getting the correct path to access a physical file

Comment: Ensure that your xslx files are included in the project before you publish using web deploy. Open your solution in Visual Studio, click `show all files` icon and then right click your xslx file and then click `include in project`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is accessible.maybe the file is not found in the desired location.

Try this where WebRootPathis your wwwwroot folder.

`private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
 Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "FileName")`

Comment: And you get the correct `IHostingEnvironment` by adding that as a parameter to the constructor of your controller.